# extjs sdk build is not created

Tags: extjs, sdk, build

i try to make a build with extjs. i created the app with architect. I start the build with this line:

```
sencha create jsb -a http://localhost/coolApp/index.html -p app.jsb3
```

this is the error i see in my terminal

```
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():2
phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():1
/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3/compat/scripts/phantomjs-jsb.js:299
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
```

this is how my app.js look like:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
models: [
    'gridPersoneel',
    'gridAuto'
],
stores: [
    'gridPersoneel',
    'gridAuto'
],
autoCreateViewport: true,
name: 'coolApp'
});
```

while my folder structure is like this:

coolApp
extjs
resources

in extjs are the sdk and extjs 4.1 files located

anyone with the same experience? I am using a Mac to make the build

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: I have similar problem while am trying to create a new sdk build.But here you are trying do an app build.So it may not be a problem for u guys.I think u are missing the ext-all/ext-debug files in the index.html

Answer (score 0):

The proper path to the ext-debug, `ext-all.css` fixed the issue. If you have specified a relative path in your `index.html`, make sure the path is pointing to the library files correctly.